# Predicting the difference or the quotient?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

For a time series forecasting problem, I noticed some people tried to predict the difference or the quotient. For instance, in trading, we can try  to predict the price difference P_{t-1} - P_t or the price quotient P_{t-1}/P_t. So we get a more stationary problem. With a recurrent neural network for a regression problem, trying to predict the price difference can be a real pain if the price does not change sufficiently fast because it will predict mostly zero at each step.

**Questions :**

1. What are the advantages and inconveniences of using the difference or the quotient instead of the whole quantity?
2. What can a nice tool to get rid of the repetitive zeros in a problem like trying to predict the price movement?

Comment: Please give us an 5 line example and a graph in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

- If the assumption is that the **price** is stationary (*P<sub>t</sub>=C<sup>te</sup>), then predict the whole quantity.
- If the assumption is that the **price increase** ()is stationary (P<sub>t</sub>= P<sub>t-1</sub>+C<sup>te</sup>), then predict the absolute difference P<sub>t</sub>-P<sub>t-1</sub>. (Note: thie is the ARIMA model with a degree of differencing=1)
- If the assumption is that the **price growth** (in percentage) is stationary (P<sub>t</sub>=P<sub>t-1</sub> +C<sup>te</sup> * P<sub>t-1</sub>), then predict the relative difference P<sub>t</sub>/P<sub>t-1</sub>.
- If the price changes **rarely** (i.e. the absolute or relative difference is most often zero), then try to predict the time interval between tow changes rather than the price itself.

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer?

Comment: With pleasure. Can you please add the first 5-6 lines of data and a graph of the full range (units do not matter).